# Android socket that controls GPIO

Tags: java, android, sockets, controls, gpio

I want to build a android app, based on a socket,that connects to a raspberry pi and has one (on off switch) or two buttons that control the GPIO state. I have only succeeded in making a simple button connection between my app and the raspberry pi, based on a IP address and port.  It controls the GPIO but with no reason after seconds it automatically changes the state from high lo low.
Do I have to control the GPIO state from the android app or from the server/client java file from the raspberry pi?

Please help ...

Answer (score 1):

For the python pin control, first install the python library:
`sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio`

The following python script will power on pin 18 (BCM numbering) and then power it down after 5 seconds:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
```

Pin numberings on raspberry pi have two kind of notations (BOARD and BCM), check [this](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-b-gpio-header-details-and-pinout/) link for a map of both. It can get easily mistaken for not working because of the two notaions, for example GPIO23 = pin 16

For the application architecture i would suggest [MQTT](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-mqtt), it is lightweight and well suited for an internet of things architecture. There are libraries for both [android](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) and [python](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) and several brokers like HiveMq and Mosquitto. I've written a demo that communicates between and android and a raspberry pi [here](https://github.com/danionescu0/robot-camera-platform) ( python part) and [here](https://github.com/danionescu0/android-robot-camera)(android part) maby it helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are asking about app architecture. I think that at RaspberryPi you should implement kind of socket listener, that has a predefined set of commands such as switch GPIO pin state, get GPIO pin state and so on. From Android side you will connect to server, retrieve state by sending appropriate command(if you need to display current GPIO state), and send predefined commands on controls click to tell server side to do something. Like this. It's my own opinion about that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... the intriging part is that i have tried several ways to run a python script that control the gpio but with no succes, but managed to control directly from the android app the gpio but with the error mentioned above! Maybe I have to make a different py file for every gpio and gpio state i want to control ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar but with a TI cc3200 over wifi p2p. I have no experience with the Raspberry Pi so keep that in mind. If your GPIO is changing state without any additional commands being sent from your app, I would look at the Raspberry for the issue. A few ideas, with your android maybe setup a break point where you send signals to the Raspberry and see if anything is happening that you didn't intend. With the Raspberry maybe setup a breakpoint in the routine where the pi receives commands. (I say that with zero knowledge of the IDE you are using for the pi.) Generally speaking breakpoints and stepping through the execution is where you find out what's happening. I think there's something about pulldown resistors and stability in microprocessors that you could research. It's been a long time since I've dealt with that kind of thing so I'm not sure, then again that may not apply to the Pi. Just a thought. And finally, maybe someone a lot smarter than me can weigh in.

Comment: The raspberry pi is working ok as i olso have a http app that connects and works just fine.